# Adding faster RAM than the CPU supports

Tags: memory

I have a computer with an Intel i7 6700HQ processor that seems to support 2133 MHz DDR4 memory. My question is: what would happen if I add DDR4 RAM running at a clock speed of 3000 MHz?

The reason I ask is because I'm currently getting 3000 MHz RAM cheaper than 2133 MHz RAM on Amazon.ca:

1. [2133 MHz for $134.99](https://www.amazon.ca/Corsair-Vengeance-2x8GB-2133MHz-Memory/dp/B019HVNT3C/ref=sr_1_16?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1484364003&sr=1-16&keywords=ddr4+8gb+2133)
2. [3000 MHz for $119.99](https://www.amazon.ca/CORSAIR-Vengeance-3000MHz-memory-Systems/dp/B0134EW7G8/ref=sr_1_5?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1484362583&sr=1-5&keywords=ddr4+8gb)

Which should I buy and why?

Comment: It will be down clocked.  Your motherboard will determine if the system will post with the memory or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually the motherboard that determines what type and speed of memory is supported. You need to check the specs for your motherboard. Also if the motherboard doesn't support 3000 MHz RAM, the RAM you want to buy may support slower speeds. So you need to check on the RAM specs as well.

Comment: Of course even if the memory and the motherboard support 3000 MHz, if the CPU only supports 2133 MHz, then that will be effective speed of the memory.